# Making a pool concept in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a structure as

```
struct Employee 
{ 
 char   uName  [255]; 
 struct   Employee *  next; 
 struct   Employee *  prev; 
};
```

All i want to allocate memory of 100 stucture objects at a time and then use them one by one i making a linked list.If the memory is consumed fully then again i want to allocate 100 object memory

I am doing the allocation as

```
struct Employee * chunk=new struct Employee[100];
```

Now when i want to add a new node to a linked list i want to take objects from this already allocated memory.Can somebody tell how to achieve this

```
Employee * pEmployeeData=NULL;
for(long int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
        pEmployeeData=EmployeePool+i;
        pEmployeeData->next=NULL;
        pEmployeeData->prev=NULL;
        InsertAtEnd(pEmployeeData);
}
```

where InsertAtEnd inserts the node at the end of the linked list.Please tell how to achieve this

Comment: I initially removed the C++ tag because this looks like C, but then I saw "new". Man, there are better ways to do this kind of thing in C++.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail of what you're stuck with?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Indeed there are - overloading `new` and delete` operators for `struct employee` to pool allocate is the usual one.

Comment: Why not use the list that already exists in the standard library [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). When you need more just push new entries at the back. And if you want 100 more at a time, just add 100 in a loop.

Comment: You could also use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as the pool, adding 100 entries at a time by using [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). If you really want them in a list as well, then add them to a `std::list` after they been allocated.

Comment: By the way, you have a problem with your loop in your example, it should probably go from `i = 0` to `i < 100`. As it is now you will not get the first entry in the pool, and you will get the last entry from one step beyond the pool. It's easier to see if you would be using e.g. `pEmployeeData=&EmployeePool[i];`

Comment: I use std:deque, rather than a list, for this, pushing on pointers to load it up, (with a lock if multithreaded use).

Comment: Also, if you really want to link up the objects explicitly, you only really need one pointer - a circular list would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you don't try to reinvent the wheel by writing your own linked list, instead have a look at the C++ standard library which contains ready-made container types available for you to use.  (for example `std::vector` and `std::list`).

Container types exist in the C++ standard library, and are used for storing collections of data/objects.   for example, you could do something along the lines of

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Employee
{
    std::string name;
    int id;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> my_employees;

    Employee fred = { "Fred", 1 };
    Employee bob = { "Bob", 2 };

    my_employees.push_back( fred );
    my_employees.push_back( bob );


    std::cout << my_employees[0].id << " " << my_employees[0].name << "\n"
              << my_employees[1].id << " " << my_employees[1].name << std::endl;
}
```

The standard containers are easy to use and to learn (You'll find plenty of internet resources which describe how to use them - and your book should also tell you!); If you're new to C++, then it's highly advisable to start out by figuring out how to use these before attempting to create your own.

Comment: With non-trivial Employee, or an employee that is going to polymorph at some stage, std::vector<*Employee> is going to be faster and safer, (or some smart_ptr).

Answer (score 0):

You'd override the `new` and `delete` operators for your class.

`new` would have to look at any existing pools and see if there were any free objects, and if there weren't, it would then need to allocate a pool.  Then, it would return memory allocated from it.

`delete` would need to check the pool that the provided object was allocated in.  If ANY object is still allocated in it, the pool stays, otherwise, it can be deleted.

Also, since you're using C++, consider using a full blown class (though there is very little difference)